# Url rewriting in .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

When clicked, a link on my page will redirect to:

```
http://www.abc.com/document.aspx?sid=42&amp;rid=1&amp;mid=1
```

I want to show it in the address bar as:

```
http://www.abc.com/models/childfirst/inbrief
```

Where

- `models` becomes the value of `rid`
- `childfirst` becomes the value of `sid`
- `inbried` becomes the value of `mid`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example URL, I'll assume you are using ASP.NET Web Forms.
If that's correct, I recommend you to check [URL Rewriting](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewriting-for-aspnet-web-forms) and [URL Friendly](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/user-friendly-url-rule-template) configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I have used urlrewriter in the past for .NET 3.5 and it works really well.

*link removed as it was no longer the tool.

Comment: Why your link take me to adult contents?

Comment: Crazy, I have removed the link. It was obviously abandoned by the original owner.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Routing Tables:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

you can also use Routing tables,

Global.asax

RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes); in application_onstart

Then create the routes needed:

routes.MapPageRoute("name", "section/{category}", "~/section/index.aspx");

then you can use:

_value = Page.RouteData.Values["category"] as string;

to the get data for each part.

Comment: ps. the urlrewriter is okay but very difficult to debug. I have tried.

Comment: routes.MapPageRoute is only gonna work in .net 4.0 not in 3.5 i think.

Answer (score 0):

Dustin Laine,
I have try the link you have given and try this but all the time its redirecting to same page,

```
<rewriter>
<rewrite url="/models/(.+)" to="/document.aspx?sid=$1&amp;rid=$2&amp;mid=$3" />
<rewrite url="/implementation/(.+)" to="/document.aspx?sid=$1&amp;rid=$2&amp;mid=$3" />
<rewrite url="/outcomes/(.+)" to="/document.aspx?sid=$1&amp;rid=$2&amp;mid=$3" />
<rewrite url="/publications/(.+)" to="/document.aspx?rid=$1&amp;sid=$2&amp;mid=$3" />
<rewrite url="/help/(.+)" to="/document.aspx?rid=$1&amp;sid=$2&amp;mid=$3" />
<rewrite url="/aboutus/(.+)" to="/document.aspx?rid=$1&amp;sid=$2&amp;mid=$3" />
<rewrite url="/review/(.+)" to="/document.aspx?rid=$1&amp;sid=$2&amp;mid=$3" />
</rewriter>
```

i think its not talking values of $1,$2,$3 beacause in my target url its like /document.aspx?sid=42&rid=1&mid=1 but when i type in url is this /models/childfirst/inbrief.